# q-Leibniz Rule?

Tags: calculus, differential-algebra, q-analogs

The famous Leibniz rule: $(uv)' = u'v+uv'$ can be generalized for any order derivative using the following formula
$$(uv)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}u^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}$$
This is a known formula which is relatively easy to prove. More on it can be read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule). I was wondering if one could create a q-analog using the q-Binomial coefficient (also known as the Gauss binomial coefficient) as demonstrated below
$$(uv)^{(n)}_q = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}_qu^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}$$
A few examples:
$$(uv)_q' = u'v+uv'$$
$$(uv)_q'' = u''v+(1+q)u'v'+uv''$$
$$(uv)_q''' = u'''v+(1+q+q^2)u''v'+(1+q+q^2)u'v''+uv'''$$
It satisfies the requirement for the definition of a q-analog as $q\rightarrow 1$ is the regular Leibniz rule. Just to clarify, I'm aware of the higher-order analogs of the q-derivative, and that they look similar in concept to the formula above, however my focus is on the general Leibniz rule for any $u$ and $v$. This extension/analog seems pretty natural and can be used to extend the concept of [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) and their higher-order forms. I was just wondering if this is actually a useful or interesting q-analog, as well as if anyone has anything they'd like to contribute. Please feel free to share whatever insights, thoughts, formulas, references, etc you like

Comment: This feels like it could be related to the idea of skew-derivations that comes up when looking at actions of quantum groups on rings

Comment: An expression very similar to yours appears at the bottom of page 342 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tsukuba-journal-of-mathematics/volume-25/issue-2/Skew-derivations-of-finite-dimensional-algebras-and-actions-of-the/10.21099/tkbjm/1496164292.full)

Comment: @Chris That is very interesting! Thank you for pointing that out